# Audio volume is maximum but when i play music its not the best maximum level yet compared to Fedora, Windows XP

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

How can i maximize the volume to highest++? (i have used alsamixer, pavumeter, etc) But none of those yet giving me more volume.

So to test it. I removed Ubuntu and installed first Windows XP the same music has very high volume level. Because i am not going to use Windows XP for that in anyway, i then installed Fedora 15/16, the audio is super max, the same like Microsoft XP gave.

Then i re-installed Ubuntu but the audio even with max level its not the maximum yet. Still its missing something. So how can i maximize more using commandline or etc etc.

I am running: `PulseAudio server version: 0.9.22-24-g67d18 (default shifted by apt-get)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be something you have done already, but just in case you have not:

If you go to the sound settings you will see that the sound goes normally only up to 100%:
[image]

But if the soundcard does not report the maximum correctly, then you might still get decent sound above 100%:

[image]

If you haven't tried this before, it might help.

Comment: how can i do this using command line? such as alsamixer ?

Comment: Amplifying over 100% causes a horrible buzz when whatever sound is played, both on pc or laptop.

Comment: If the audio hardware communicates perfectly with linux, then you should not go above 100% as it will not sound good. BUT: some audio hardware does report the 100% wrongly and is therefore not as loud as in other OSs, which seemed to be the case in the original question.